# Sql Alchemy BinaryExpression when using contains() or in_(), but not operators like == or >

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use a scalar_subquery() in sql alchemy to dynamically build out a filter. This code looks something like this:

```
subquery = (session.query(some_model).filter(some_filter).correlate('some_model_alias').scalar_subquery()
)

main_query = (session.query(some_other_model))
```

Then I try to build out a dynamic filter with multiple filters by creating a list of filters

filter

```
_list = []
for filter in filters:
    filter_list.extend([subquery == some_value])

main_query.filter(and_(*filter_list))
```

This works great except for when I try to do anything other than a basic operation like .contains() or .in_()

For example if my subquery filters on

```
filter_list.extend([subquery.contains(some_value]))
```

This evaluates the subquery. The resulting list for the first example is:

```
[<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x169acd940>, <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x169acd940>]
```

but when you try to do the first filter as '==' and the second filter as '.contains()' is evaluates the query before adding it to the main query. This returns None.

```
[<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x169acd940>, None]
```